# Quicksort template does not work, and makes my program unresponsive

Tags: c++, algorithm, quicksort

I am trying to sort a vector of birthdays (using my implementation of quicksort), and also change the order of two vectors containing names and birthdates based on how they change. I followed an online source on how to implement quicksort, but I am not exactly sure why it will not work. Here is my code:

```
template <class T>
void sortBDay(vector<T> &birthday, vector<string> &name, vector<T> &birthdate, int startPos, int size) { // This template sorts all data by their birthday
    if (startPos < size - 1) { // if the first value is less than the last value
        T pivotVal = birthday[startPos]; // the pivot value is the vector's first value
        int pivotPos = startPos; // the pivot position is the vector's starting position
        for (int pos = startPos + 1; pos <= size; pos++) { // repeat for all values of vector
            if (birthday[pos] < pivotVal) { // if the current position is less than the starting position
                swap(birthday[pivotPos + 1], birthday[pos]);
                swap(birthday[pivotPos], birthday[pivotPos + 1]); // switch the positions

                swap(name[pivotPos + 1], name[pos]); // and their names
                swap(name[pivotPos], name[pivotPos + 1]);

                swap(birthdate[pivotPos + 1], birthdate[pos]); // and their birthdates
                swap(birthdate[pivotPos], birthdate[pivotPos + 1]);
                pivotPos++; // then go onto the next one
            }
            sortBDay(birthday, name, birthdate, startPos, size - 1); // do the same for upper and lower pivots
            sortBDay(birthday, name, birthdate, startPos, size + 1); // recursion
        }   
    }
}
```

I don't know what's wrong with this implementation. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: `pos <= size` - that doesn't look good at all. This would be considerably cleaner if all this data were in a single vector of objects rather than three distinct vectors. And fwiw, [`std::partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) makes short work of the quicksort algorithm, including eliminating the mistakes made here. The linked document even has a usage example that does just that; implements quicksort.

Comment: Do I need to add in the separate partition function, or can I keep it all together?

Comment: You can keep it all together if you want to use your own partition algorithm, certainly.

Comment: Is this an assignment of some kind? Do you have to implement quicksort yourself?

Comment: Yes, this is an assignment. And yes, I did need to implement this myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put a recursion in a loop, that's not how quick sort works. And the start and end position passed to the recursion function were not correct.

Here is the fix. I changed the parameter `size` to `end` because that's how the variable in your code behaves like.

```
template <class T>
void sortBDay(vector<T> &birthday, vector<string> &name, vector<T> &birthdate, int startPos, int end) { // This template sorts all data by their birthday
    if (startPos < end - 1) { // if the first value is less than the last value
        T pivotVal = birthday[startPos]; // the pivot value is the vector's first value
        int pivotPos = startPos; // the pivot position is the vector's starting position
        for (int pos = startPos + 1; pos < end; pos++) { // repeat for all values of vector
            if (birthday[pos] < pivotVal) { // if the current position is less than the starting position
                swap(birthday[pivotPos + 1], birthday[pos]);
                swap(birthday[pivotPos], birthday[pivotPos + 1]); // switch the positions

                swap(name[pivotPos + 1], name[pos]); // and their names
                swap(name[pivotPos], name[pivotPos + 1]);

                swap(birthdate[pivotPos + 1], birthdate[pos]); // and their birthdates
                swap(birthdate[pivotPos], birthdate[pivotPos + 1]);
                pivotPos++; // then go onto the next one
            }
        }   

        sortBDay(birthday, name, birthdate, startPos, pivotPos); // do the same for upper and lower pivots
        sortBDay(birthday, name, birthdate, pivotPos + 1, end); // recursion
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll be sure to test this once I'm home. Sorry for the late response.

Comment: You're welcome. I just learned that this is an assignment. Hope that you will carefully review this quick-sort code and understand it.

Comment: The code inside the loop is to place the elements smaller than the pivot in front of it. Then comes the two recursions. The first one should recurse the range from start to the pivot, and the second one recuse the range pivot+1 to the end. A small quiz for you, do we have to put the pivot in the first recursion?

Comment: Yes, in the first recursion (sortBDay(birthday, name, birthdate, startPos, pivotPos);), the pivot helps in sorting all values from 0 to the pivot, and sorting them. Then the second recursion sorts all values from the pivot onwards.